# The process of generating missing values by NMAR

Tags: r, simulation, missing-data

The process of generating missing values by NMAR:

```
Aj <- c(48,75,83,58,83,32,45,50,86)
```

NMAR produced missingness on every variable directly. For a given variable Aj and specified missing rate α, if Aj is numerical, we first calculated the median of Aj and then randomly let the values that are lower (or higher) than to be missing with probability of 2α.

`α` is missing rate for example `%5 ,%10 , ....`

My question How to generate NMAR by the above way in r . I very need it

Comment: Check out the following article:
http://www.r-bloggers.com/imputing-missing-data-with-r-mice-package/

Answer (score 2):

NMAR means "not missing at random", so it means there is a pattern to your missing data. NMAR doesn't specify what that pattern will be, just that there is one.

This is a challenge for data analysis, because it means the missing data does not have the same distribution as the complete data, and therefore it is dangerous to impute the missing values based on the observed values (e.g. by imputing medians).

Even a sophisticated missing data imputation package like mice (mentioned in a comment above) is designed for imputing data which is MAR (missing at random) or MCAR (missing completely at random).

To simulate NMAR data, you simply need to specify a distribution for your missing data which is different from the distribution used to generate the data in your example. There are countless ways of doing this.

If I understand you description correctly, you would like to make 5-10% of values either below or above your median value missing. This single line of code will do it with 5% likelihood on any value above the median:

```
Aj[Aj > median(Aj)] = ifelse(sample(c(T, F), length(Aj[Aj > median(Aj)]), replace=T, prob=c(0.05, 0.95)), NA, Aj[Aj > median(Aj)])
```

This line of code is taking the Aj values which are above the median, and then the ifelse() uses a sample to pick either the first option (T with 5% likelihood) or the second option (F with 95% likelihood). If T, the value is replaced with NA. If F, the original value is kept.